# Adding a background on inputs for convolutional neural net?

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, yolo

I'm trying to train a neural net using YOLOv2 to recognize characters and objects in a video game. For input data, I took screen shots of in game assets from various angles. However, there are no backgrounds in these character models - only the models themselves. In the game, of course, there will be backgrounds behind the characters.

Will this confuse the neural network? And if so, should I go ahead and find some sample background images from the game and apply them randomly to the input data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should add ingame backgrounds to your models or you will never get a decent quality detection. The network needs to know the background, placement of the objects on the background, even the lighting of the objects in the scene. They all contribute to the final detection quality.

Also the technique you use to blend the background and your images is important.

A good read about the subject: [Synthesizing Training Data for Object Detection in
Indoor Scenes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.07836.pdf)